# Handling post request error properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My rails controller index method reads post requests. However, when the application first starts, the post request does not exist and it throws a

> undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

To account for this condition, I have the following block of code. Basically, if reading the post request generates an error it sets a value manually.

```
begin
    @business = params[:business_name]
rescue
    @business = ["Nestle"]
end
```

I have a feeling this is a poor approach to solve this problem. What would be a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@business = !params.nil? ? ( params[:business_name] || "Nestle" ) : "Nestle"
```

I do wonder about how the application is hitting a controller method without a request from a browser. Normally the browser issues a GET request for the page opened and that request gets routed to the controller method. A basic `unless request.post?` followed by a block to set up the default values for the page if none were specified is a straightforward way of handling non-POST requests for an index page.

Answer (score 0):

`@business = !params[:business_name].nil? || ["Nestle"]`

Comment: So, that doesn't work because making the params[:business_name] call generates an error, so it never gets to the ["Nestle"] part.

Comment: That's what I am having trouble with.. it seems that I can't just check for a nil because as soon as you call a params[] on a non-existent parameter, it errors out

Comment: That's odd, rails normally returns nil if the parameter does not exist.

Comment: It's been awhile but check out my edit and see if that helps at all.

Comment: Based on the operator reported, it's the `params` variable itself that's `nil`. I'm not entirely sure how that's possible, it should at least be an empty collection.